# mobile app which should be run in any platform using VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile app which should work in android or ios or windows and I want use Visual Studio 2012 as a development platform. So please guide me what suitable other technologies should be use to develop this mobile app?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for "cross-platform mobile .Net development", google will be your friend, but I have used [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/) before with success to produce a mobile app in C# which we then deployed on Android and iOS.

An alternative is to look at HTML5 development to target multiple platforms, suites such as Telerik's [AppBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder) go down this route and also provide Visual Studio IDE integration.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio 2012:**
Using Visual Studio 2012 you can only develop app for windows platform.

**Windows:**
Use Visual Studio 2012 to develop it

**Android** 
use Eclipse to develop.

**iOS**
Use Xcode to develop.

Use **Phone Gap** to develop cross platform coding. Eclipse IDE is recommended for it.